# ImportError: No module named control

Tags: python, import, celery

I have a celery app, my files like this:

```
  /fetcher.py
  /mirad
       celery.py
       fetcher_tasks.py
```

in `celery.py` i was import `fetcher_tasks.py`
and in fetcher.py i call a task from fetcher_tasks.py
i want to import `celery.control` in fetcher.py but i can't do it, how i can do this work?

this is a part of my fetcher code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import mirad.fetcher_tasks as tasks
from mirad.models.models import SourceModel
from mirad.settings import *
from mirad.celery.control import inspect


parse_feed_tasks = list()

def fetch():

        for source in SourceModel.objects(active=True):
            a = tasks.parse_feed.delay(source)
```

Comment: I don't understand the code you've shown. What is `mirad`? Does a `control.py` file exist somewhere in your package?

Comment: @Blckknght , i edited it! I don't have control.py, I want to import [this](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.control.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you mix celery.py in your project which is used to start Celery app with celery package from which you can import necessery functions.

You should import `inspect` function from `celery.task.control` package.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import mirad.fetcher_tasks as tasks
from mirad.models.models import SourceModel
from mirad.settings import *
from celery.task.control import inspect

parse_feed_tasks = list()

def fetch():

        for source in SourceModel.objects(active=True):
            a = tasks.parse_feed.delay(source)
```